# App authentication dialog box for facebook app

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made an facebook app. Now i need to take user information using a pop-up permission box. If a user has authenticated the app, facebook should not open dialog box for permission but if a user comes to app first time then it must open a dialog box.  What I am trying to do here is...and getting error like...

Cannot call method 'showPermissionDialog' of undefined

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
               if (response.status === 'connected') {
                   alert("1");
                   // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                   // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                   // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                   // request, and the time the access token
                   // and signed request each expire
                   var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                   //alert(uid);
                   var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                   jQuery("#<%= accessToken.ClientID %>").val(accessToken);
                   // alert(accessToken);
                   fqlQuerynew();
               } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

                   // the user is logged in to Facebook,
                   // but has not authenticated your app
                   alert('not_authorized');

                   OnRequestPermission();
               } else {
                   alert("3");
                   //alert('the user isnt logged in to Facebook');
               }
           });


       };

       function OnRequestPermission() {
           var myPermissions = "publish_stream, manage_pages"; // permissions your app needs
           FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email,offline_access", function (perms) {
               if (!perms) {
                   alert("hi");
                   // document.location.href = 'YouNeedToAuthorize.html';
               } else {
                   alert("buy");
                   document.location.href = 'homePage.html';
               }
           });
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have just copied and pasted it from your code then I think you have added one extra closing bracket after FB.getLoginStatus '};'.

After removing that try your code. If it doesn't work then can we know when you want to check login status like after clicking some social button or while loading page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of your code, I haven't tested it and it's not complete, but should give you an idea of what to do:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        jQuery("#<%= accessToken.ClientID %>").val(accessToken);
        fqlQuerynew();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        OnRequestPermission();
    } else {
        ...
    }
});

function OnRequestPermission() {
    var myPermissions = "publish_stream, manage_pages"; // permissions your app needs
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api("me/permissions", checkPermissions);
        }
        else {
            ....
        }
    }, { scope: "email,offline_access" });
}

function checkPermissions(response) {
    if (response.data && response.data.legth == 1) {
        var perms = response.data[0];
        // iterate over perms and check if the user has all needed permissions
    }
}
```